# How to connect netbeans to oracle db from another network? Im using Oracle XE 11g

Tags: java, database, oracle, networking

I'm trying to connect and here's my connection code.

URL:

```
private static final String url = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@192.168.1.29:1521:XE";
```

The connection works when it's on the same pc but when I import it on another pc, it does not connect. How do I fix this? What are the things I should check?

Comment: Which errors do you get ?

Comment: It can't get the data from the DB

Comment: Oh i got it, turns out both our firewalls are up.